# Surface GUI Text Change Not Working On Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

Im currently developing a british army game and this doesnt seem to work, the text doesnt change. Should I change the script location?

```
if wall.CanCollide == true then
    status.Text = Active
end

if wall.CanCollide == false then
    status.Text = Not Active
end

Any thoughs?
```

I changed the text to string then took away the strings, did a loop, took the loop away...

Answer (score 0):

```
local a
wall:GetPropertyChangedSignal"CanCollide":Connect(function()
    if a then
        return
    end
    a = true
    status.Text = (not wall.CanCollide and "Not "or"") .. "Active"
    a = false
end)
```

Comment: And why is tha sntax?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I believe I see the problem here. Try this code out this time.

```
if wall.CanCollide == true then
    status.Text = "Active"
else
    status.Text = "Not Active"
end
```